# creating postcard with data on front and back

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to print out postcards (4 perforated 4.25 x 5.5 cards per page) with the name and address on one side, and their corresponding appointment information on the other.

I'm not sure how to do this in Crystal.

I've tried different variables writing such as remainder(recordnumber,4)=0 under the Section Expert, Detail, NewPageAfter and this didn't work. If anyone has any tips or suggestions, this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the Group Footer into two sections.

You put the normal "New Page After" on 2.  You don't check "New Page After" on 1 but instead you give the "New Page After" a formula:

```
   Remainder (PageNumber,2) = 1
```

This way, when the group ends on an odd page, the report will have an extra blank page so that the group ends on the even, and the new group starts on the odd.

You can read more [here](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1701418)

Answer (score 0):

I've never made postcards, but I've made reports for printing 2-sided business cards and convention badges, and the concept is similar.

The general idea is to create a report where the page size is equal to the size of a single sheet of your postcard stock (in this case its a normal page size of 8.5 x 11 with portrait layout).  Then in your section expert for your details section you will want to check the box on the Common tab to enable "Format with Multiple Columns".  This should add a Layout tab in Section Expert where you can set the size of each postcard on the sheet.  This should allow your report to know there will be 4 cards per page.

Right click on your details section and create a second details section after the first.  Then enable the New Page After property of the first details section.  This will force the first details section to be page 1, repeated 4 times, then the second details section becomes page 2, repeated 4 times.

The front of the postcards will be designed in first (page 1) details section, while the back of the cards will be designed in the second (page 2) details section.

When you print your report, make sure you have 2-sided printing or full duplex turned on so that it knows to print on both sides of the paper stock being used.

This should be enough to get you started!

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports 11 if I did not mention it before. I don't think this version lets me set individual postcard sizes in the layout section.