# How do I print 2-sided postcards from SSRS with different data on front and back

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I need to design a postcard report that will print the mailing address on one side, and other info on the other side. Portions of both sides will come from our database. How do I design the report so that it will print correctly, that is Page 1 = Postcard Front, and Page 2 = Postcard Back)? (our printer will print duplex)
 I saw these 2 similar articles, but neither one addresses exactly what I need to do, since I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (not Crystal Reports), and I have 4 documents per page (I guess 2 documents plus 2 columns as far as designing is concerned) instead of just 1 document per page.

[this article deals with 1 document per page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9de09bbf-218e-469b-b5aa-4e9712506313/ssrs-print-report-on-both-sides-on-same-document?forum=sqlreportingservices)

[and this article deals with Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519806/creating-postcard-with-data-on-front-and-back)

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, but I have it returning all the fronts in order and then all the backs. I'm assuming the printer can handle the collating. Interested to see if you find a solution for alternating pages.

Comment: StevenWhite - Could you tell me how you are doing the fronts in order, then the backs? That may work fine for us; I'd like to test it out anyway.

Comment: Here's one example of a similar situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331822/sql-server-report-builder-for-shipping-labels-one-per-page/54332391#54332391